# require vs import syntax in react-codemirror2

Tags: codemirror, react-codemirror2

Totally confused by this example in react-codemirror2 which uses both `import` and `require` syntax;
[See https://github.com/scniro/react-codemirror2 in the section `requiring codemirror resources`]

```
import CodeMirror from 'react-codemirror2'; 
require('codemirror/mode/xml/xml'); 
require('codemirror/mode/javascript/javascript');
```

I know the require('codemirror/etc') stuff is referring to a plain JS library dependency (not React specific), but why does `require` even work without throwing an error?

Can the `require` be replaced by an `import`?
How to make the warning in VS Code editor go away?
[image]

Answer (score 0):

The main idea of this part of the Docs is that you need to require by yourself CodeMirror modules that you needed (it means that if you need a javascript mode or autocomplete, you need to add these modules to your code).

`react-codemirror2` doc says that:

> How to import/require these assets will vary according to the
> specifics of your development environment

In most cases, both `require` and `import` will do the same, so you can use the code that is given in `react-codemirror2` docs:

```
import CodeMirror from 'react-codemirror2'; 
require('codemirror/mode/xml/xml'); 
require('codemirror/mode/javascript/javascript');
```

or use its analog with imports:

```
import CodeMirror from 'react-codemirror2'; 
import 'codemirror/mode/xml/xml'; 
import 'codemirror/mode/javascript/javascript';
```